# Add value until another cell value is reached

Tags: excel-formula

Could you please help me find a solution to a problem that i have in Excel? I don't know exactly if this could be achieved in Excel, so any ideea would be highly appreciated.

So, i have a very big production sheet. 
- On column B i have the dates (in this format: 01.01.2019, 02.01.2019, 03.01.2019, etc);
- On column C i have the proposed production per day;
- On column D i have the current stock;
- On column E i have the medium request / day

Regarding the fact that the values on column E are changing depending on the client's request, sometimes will be bellow 10 days (out policy is to have a minimum 10 days stock). When this happends, i have to delete everything on column C and replan the production so the values in column E won't be bellow 10.

I was thinking about a formula in column C to do something like this: if E1<10, add 200 in c1. If after this e1 is still smaller than 10, add another 200.

The other problem is that our maximum production capacity / week is, let's say 2000 pcs (in column C), meaning a maximum of 400 pcs / day. So the formula should add 200, on 01.01.2019, then if column E is not 10, it should add another 200, but if column C is still not 10, the formula should go to 02.01.2019 and repeat the steps...
Also, if until the end of the week the value in column E is still not 10, it should repeat the steps begining from next monday (no production on saturday or sunday)

I attached a screenshot of my actual table (left) and another one with the desired result (right).

Is there any chance i can do something like this with a formula or it can only be achieved with VBA?

I really hope i made myself understood, english is not my native language and as i think you see, i'm not an excel expert...

Thank you so much in advance for any help or ideea you can give me.
\Cheers

[image: Actual table]
[image: Desired table]

Comment: *if E1<10, add 200 in c1. If after this e1 is still smaller than 10, add another 200*. But how does the value in `E1` change in this process?

Comment: You could look at using the solver with the changing cells as the values in column C and the constraints of col E to be less than or equal to 10. Have not got time to try it sorry.

Comment: I agree with @lurker, how is the Medium Request / day (column E) affected in this process? When you add production per day how do you want it to affect `E1`? I also don't understand your right picture. At date 2019-01-16 you have 10 in column E, but you still want to add 400 in production that day?